# Appending csv files in directory into a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, csv, web-scraping, append

I have written a scraper which downloads daily flight prices, stores them as pandas data frames and saves them off as csv files in a given folder. I am now trying to combine these csv files into pandas for data analysis using append, but end result is an empty data frame.

Specifically, individual csv files are loaded correctly into pandas, but the append seems to fail (and several methods found on stackoverflow posts don't seem to work). Code is below, any pointers? Thanks!

```
directory = os.path.join("C:\\Testfolder\\")

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        daily_flight_df = (pd.read_csv(directory+file,sep=";")) #loads csv into dataframe - works correctly
        cons_flight_df.append(daily_flight_df) #appends daily flight prices into a pandas with consolidated flight prices - does not seem to work

print(cons_flight_df) #currently prints out an empty data frame

cons_flight_df.to_csv('C:\\Testfolder\\test.csv') #currently returns empty csv file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas, the append method isn't in place.  You need to assign  it.

```
cons_flight_df = cons_flight_df.append(daily_flight_df)
```